# Encode Array with NSCoder

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsobject, nscoder

I have a User `Class` that uses a `saveuser()` method whenever the application terminates.  The User has two `Arrays` of Custom `Classes` that sub-class `NSObject`.  Here is my encode method.

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(self.firstName, forKey: coderKey.fName)
    aCoder.encode(self.lastName, forKey: coderKey.lName)
    aCoder.encode(self.bio, forKey: coderKey.bio)
    aCoder.encode(self.tags, forKey: coderKey.tags)
    aCoder.encode(self.organizations, forKey: coderKey.orgs)
    aCoder.encode(self.img, forKey: coderKey.img)
}
```

The app Crashes when encoding  `self.tags`.  I assume it will do the same with `self.organizations` because it is also an `array` of `NSObjects` and possibly with `self.img` because it is a `UIImage`.  Here is the error I am getting.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Social_Justice.Tag encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000005efc0'

What should I do to resolve this issue?  If you need to see any more code, just comment and i'll edit.

Comment: Your two custom classes will also need to implement NSCoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as David Berry commented on the original post.  You have to Make sure any custom classes that you are trying to encode, also conform to NSCoder.  They don't need to have archive paths, they just need to have the encode and decode functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

1. I assume the class name of the object inside the array self.tag**s** and self.organization**s** are **Tag** and **Organization**
2. Objective-C use a very different function calling style. If you see `[ClassName/ObjectName methodName]` which is somehow equivalent to `ObjectName.function()` style in Swift, let's put it in this way for the moment (the Swift compiler will be better in the future, and hopefully you will not see objctive-C warnings anymore when debugging)
3. A *selector* is a term used by Objective-C, you could think this is a method. Therefore this unrecognized selector error warning tells you the code tried to call a method named `encodeWithCode()` that doesn't actually exist inside the object  **Tag** and **Organization** (the NSCoder system knows how to encode an array, but has no idea to encode your own object inside Array)
4. If you want to use the 5 concrete classes of the `NSCoder` system on an object, the object **MUST** conform the `NSCoding` protocol. It means the class (**Tag** and **Organization**) must implement `init?(coder: NSCoder)` and `func encode(with: NSCoder)`
5. The 4 concrete class of `NSCoder` are `NSArchiver, NSUnarchiver, NSKeyedArchiver, NSKeyedUnarchiver, and NSPortCoder.`

**Further Reading:**

[NSCoding / NSKeyed​Archiver By NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/)

Or: (my favorite)

[Apple Document NSCoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoder)

[Apple Document NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver)

[Apple Document NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding)

Or: (If those documents are still a bit confuse for you)

**Hollemans M.** 2016, iOS Apprentice Fifth Edition Tutorial 2 Checklist, pp 126 ~ pp 137